# Authenticate to SharePoint using Client Id and Client Secret with python Requests module

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, https

I would like to authenticate to SharePoint using Python and the Requests package. This is what I have so fare:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

client_id = 'my_client_id'
client_secret = 'my_client_secret'
sitepath = 'https://our_sites.company_name.com/sites/my_site'

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuthSession(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='super_long_token_url',
                          client_id=client_id,
                          client_secret=client_secret)
```

However a "ValueError: Please supply either code or authorization_response parameters"

Ideally I was hoping to use the client_id and client_secret basically as a user and password. In any case, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access SharePoint Online using Python and use client_id and client_secret to pass the authentication, here is a project from GitHub for your reference.

[O365 - Microsoft Graph and Office 365 API made easy](https://github.com/O365/python-o365#sharepoint)

If you want to use username and password to pass the authentication, we can use this.

[Office 365 & Microsoft Graph Library for Python](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate client id and client secret using below link:
https://YourSharePointOnlineSiteUrl/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

Once generated you can use below site to give access to id created:
https://YourSharePointOnlineSiteUrl/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

Give appid as client id

Appdomain as: localhost
redirect url as : https://localhost.com
permission as below: